# alexa custom skill not working in Reverb

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have developed a custom skill, which is working well with Alexa test tool, but even after enabling the skill on Alexa app, it is not working with reverb.

PS:

- I'm running skill server locally on my computer with the help of reverse proxy.
- skill is not published yet.
- I've logged in with the same account on both reverb and Alexa app.
- Language is set to US English in both apps and in skill config.

Comment: please check the alexa device whether that region is configured or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it. had to say  "ask ***skill-name*** to ***[do some operation]***" instead of "start ***skill-name***". reason unknown.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke skill in two ways:
- Invoking a Skill with a Specific Request (Intent)
- Invoking a Skill with No Specific Request (No Intent)

Comment: please explain more details :)!

Answer (score -1):

Better use [echosim.io](https://echosim.io/) than reverb.

Comment: did that, no luck either.